# How do I set a string field to NULL in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

If I type NULL, it is treated as a string literal.  If I leave it blank it is treated as an empty string.

Comment: Are you talking about setting it in the table definition, or when setting the value of a column in a row?

Comment: And if you're talking about setting a column value, are you using the Insert tab, or an actual SQL statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There must be a checkbox near input for setting NULL value. ( only on nullable columns )

( alternatievly, I prefer to use SQL language directly )

Answer (score 3):

In phpMyAdmin, there should be a checkbox next to the text field.  Checking that should make the field NULL.

If you're using a query, it is:

```
UPDATE table SET field = NULL WHERE id = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tick the checkbox in the NULL column (and make sure that NULL is allowed for that field).